# Override a single variable from entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Context:

I have 2 projects, 
Project 1: defines all the entities of hibernate to map classes to database. This particular project is used in multiple other projects as the structure of the database in general remains same.
Project 2: Utilizes Project 1 for database access.

Problem:
I need to expand a column in the database specific to "Project 2" from Num(5,0) to num(20,0).

Restrictions:
I can not touch code in "project 1". Entities in the "Project 1" CAN NOT be changed currently, so I need to find a work around.

Question : 
Is it possible to extend the existing entity class and configure it in such a way that for a certain column the variable from the child class is used by the ORM and not of the base class. 
If that would be possible, I can simply expand the column in the database and ask ORM to use the child implementation of overridden mapping... am I even on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

So define an `"orm.xml"` (in your other project) that overrides the mapping for that field.

Comment: if it's possible to override the mapping using orm.xml, I think it should be possible to do with annotations too, right?

Comment: I meant annotating the derived class.... how difficult would it be to extend the class by the way? what complications can rise up?

Comment: My answer says why bother with a derived class when you can just have a simple orm.xml file.

Comment: a derived class would be needed because in the current entity class, the variable is defined as "Integer" and it will not be able to store the 20 digit long integer and hence I need to create a variable, possibly of type BigInteger and then map that one to the column..... can orm.xml do that? I really am new to this orm stuff...

Comment: if the base class has the FIELD as persistable then you won't be overriding anything; you can only change the superclass when it is PROPERTY. And your question doesn't define that. And even if you are using PROPERTY, you then have to look at where there are reference to the base class in other classes ... and you're expecting it to use some subclass magically?!

Comment: Okay, may be i understand your question now.  Right now there is a class (let's name it Eextn) in Project 2 that extends the Entity class in Project 1 (Let's name it E). Eextn is used throughout the Project 2 already and it essentially adds another column to the table already. And yea, a change in datatype would require me to check the references to the variable and class throughout the code base (true headache).